# How to increase a div DIV within a TD to be bigger than the TD

Tags: css

I have a table column with a div and a input-field (vue.js but that shouldnt be relevant). When the input field gets the focus I want that the DIV containing my input field to get enlarged so that it overflows across parts of the table.
When I write "overflow" I dont (necessarily) mean the "overflow" attribute in CSS but rather the effect that the DIV overflows part of the table.
Also I want the table structure to remain the same. That is the column width and row heights of the other TDs and TRs has to remain the same.

Maybe it would be easier to envision a solution without an input field but instead just the DIV that reacts to the hover event.

```
<table class="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td><div>THIS SHOULD BE ENLARGED ON FOCUS OR HOVER 300px x 200px</div></td>
        <td><div>some other data</div></td>
        <td><div>some other data</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am just looking for the CSS part of the solution. The event handling is OK.

Also the solution is NOT to increase the width of the TD or the height of the TR

Comment: Use transform scale

Comment: Downvoting and Close Voting are not necessarily related to the same person.

Comment: This question is unclear. You want it to overflow but don't want to use *overflow*. You want it to get wider but don't want its *width* to change. What *do* you want? Perhaps more importantly, what is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could use ***transform: scale*** to enlarge the content beyond its bounds, the enlargement will not create overflow either. There is however no way to set it to a specific pixel amount that I am aware of using CSS.

You can however control the size of your element in pixels and use the scale to enlarge by that amount. So if your element is 200px wide and you scale by 1.5, it will be 300px wide. If it is 50px high you could scale the y axis by 4 to get the 200px, though this will skew the content in the container to fit its bounds.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.target').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.clientWidth * 1.5 + 'px', e.target.clientHeight * 4 + 'px')
  })
})
```

```css
.my-table tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.my-table td:nth-of-type(1),
.my-table td:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.my-table .doube-scale {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.my-table .doube-scale:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5, 4);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.single-scale:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="doube-scale target">THIS SHOULD BE ENLARGED ON FOCUS OR HOVER 300px x 200px</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>some other data</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>some other data</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- This element will not be the size you want however, it will not skew the
      content as the aspect ratio will be the same regardless of the scale amount -->
      <div class="single-scale target">THIS SHOULD BE ENLARGED ON FOCUS OR HOVER</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand that your answer somehow solves the question in nominally. However everything gets scaled up too. Which is undesired.
The reason why I mentioned the input field is because the issue I am trying to sove is this.
I have a text field that can contain much more text than is possible to show in the column table due to strapped screen estate. When it gets the focus I want to increase the input field itself without scaling the font size for example.

Answer (score 1):

As dale landry already said, scaling might be a way to go. There might be a problem, though: when scaling the div, the content of that div will be scaled, too. If you don't want that, you have to scale your content "back" separately.

Another way might be positioning your div absolute and giving it an additional padding to prevent your content from jumping:

```
.double-scale-target {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: see my comment in Dale's answer. So yeah I would need to scale back but that really asks for more trouble I think <sigh>

Comment: How about absolute positioning then?