# Moving focus to the next input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move the focus to the next input element without knowing what that next element is using `TAB`.

**Background**
I have a table and I am pretty restricted on screen estate.
One of the columns in that table has an text field that may contain more text than fits into the width of the column. In order for the user to be able to enter text and simultanously see all of that text without scrolling within the input field I need to enlarge/widen the input field.
Now this enlargement shall only happen when the input field receives the focus and it should shrink when the focus moves into another input element.
HOWEVER: I dont want to simply enlarge the column containing the input field as this would yield a constant rerendering of the whole table on receiving and loosing the focus for said input fields which is pretty ugly and confusing for the user.

**My Solution so far**
When receiving an `onfocus` event for an input element that shall be enlarged I
set the colspan of the containing TD of that element to some value `X` (X being the number of columns this TD should be enlarged) and I set `display: none` for the `X - 1` TDs within that same TR right of the TD containing the input element with the focus.
When I receive an `onblur` event I revert all of this. That is the TD with the input element that had the focus and is loosing it now gets a `colspan=1` and the next `X-1` TDs right of the TD containing that input field are set to `display: table-cell`

**Problem**
All of the above works as expected in terms of rerendering. That is there is just a little bit of "jumpiness" (for lack of a better word). However the the focus does not move to the "next" input element which would be the one that was adjacent to the inputfield that just had the focus and that is visible again now but it moves to the first TD containing an input field that was not hidden.

**Example**
Lets assume a table of 5 columns and 3 rows where each TD contains an input field.
The columns labeled A-E and the rows labeled 1-3.
All columns have the same width of 20%.
Column A is the one that should enlarge *only* the one TD that has the input field with the focus.
So A2 receives the focus and sets the `colspan=3` then B2 and C2 are set to `display: none`.
As soon as the input field of A2 receives an `onblur` event everything will be reverted.
A2 `colspan=1` and B2 and C2 `display: table-cell`.
After that D2 has the focus and that is my problem.

**Approaches**
I do understand that I could be a matrix with references to all input elements and then `setFocus` accordingly. However that is a lot of wiring which I really dislike and most likey it will be brittle.
The easiest way would be if I somehow could "recalc" the blur event which already contains the next focus target. And obviously for "calculating" that target it doesnt use any hidden elements.
Another option would be if I could simply issue a command like `move the focus 2 elements back`.
A 3rd option would be to somehow extract the input field with the focus out of the table/TD and have overlay the table itself. I tried to explain this in this question [How to increase a div DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793574/how-to-increase-a-div-div-within-a-td-to-be-bigger-than-the-td) but I havent found the proper magic CSS words to do that.

Comment: Could you add the ("*[mcve]*") code that reproduces your problem? I'd argue that manipulating the `colspan` attribute is probably not the way to go, is the data genuinely tabular, or are you you trying to take advantage of a `<table>` for layout purposes? Could CSS Grid be a better fit, or a form of lists, nested or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason the next input doesn't get focused is due to the order of events.  When you're in the inputand hit tab, the blur event happens *after* the field loses focus.  Which means some other input has received focus *before* the blur event happens.  Since you can't focus on a hidden input, focus shifts to the next visible input.

So what can you do?  Well, you can't change the order of events.  But perhaps you can change your overall approach.  Rather than doing all that shifting of table layouts, what if you just create a new input, positioned absolutely in the same cell as the input that needs to grow.  That would eliminate all the jumpiness. Plus, if you place the absolutely positioned input *after* the initial input, [Tab]-ing out will automatically go to the next field.

```css
td{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
input:focus{
  border:2px solid red;
}
.long{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:300px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<table border = "1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type = "text" value = "text here">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type = "text" value = "other field" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type = "text" value = "text here">
      <input type = "text" value = "long text here" class = "long" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type = "text" value = "other field" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice when the long input is focused, then tabbed out of, the input in the next column gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the inspiration of @qausipickle above
I came up with this solution

```css
td{
  position:relative;
}
input:focus{
  border:2px solid red;
}
input:focus.long{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:300px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
  <table border = "1">
      <tr>
         <td>
             <input type = "text" value = "first long text" class="long">
         </td>
         <td>
             <input type = "text" value = "other field" />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
               <input 
                    type = "text" 
                    value = "second long text" 
                    class = "long" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type = "text" value = "other field" />
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```